# Laravel alongside WordPress on a shared host

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, shared-hosting, laravel-6

I have an wordpress website on a shared host and I want to create a laravel adminpanel for it.
I've worked based on **[this page](https://dev.to/asapabedi/deploying-laravel-5-applications-on-shared-hosting-without-the-use-of-ssh--16a6)** and my file structure is like this:

```
domains/
│
└── mydomain.com/
    │
    ├── laravel/
    │    │
    │    └── laravel files
    │
    └── public_html/
          │
          ├── wordpress files
          │
          └── appadmin/
              │
              ├── css/
              │
              ├── fonts/
              │
              ├── js/
              .
              .
              .
              │
              ├── .htaccess
              │
              └── index.php
```

And changed `appadmin/index.php` for access to `laravel` files.
index.php:

```php
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));


require __DIR__.'/../../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
//...
```

my laravel admin login route is `/login`that means laravel admin login url is `mydomain.com/appadmin/login` and it works fine.

**BUT!** when i enter username and password (doesn't matter wrong or right) and hit the submit button, page will redirect to `mydomain.com/wp-login.php`

**Edit:** these are laravel and wp `.htaccess` files

wp htaccess:

```
# BEGIN iThemes Security - این خط را تغییر یا حذف نکنید
# iThemes Security Config Details: 2
    # مسدودسازی میزبان - امنیت > تنظیمات > کاربران مسدود شده
    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^5\.45\.69\.4$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^5\.45\.69\.4$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^5\.45\.69\.4$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^192\.99\.15\.141$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^192\.99\.15\.141$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^192\.99\.15\.141$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^149\.56\.241\.211$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^149\.56\.241\.211$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^149\.56\.241\.211$" DenyAccess

    SetEnvIF REMOTE_ADDR "^31\.222\.187\.197$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "^31\.222\.187\.197$" DenyAccess
    SetEnvIF X-CLUSTER-CLIENT-IP "^31\.222\.187\.197$" DenyAccess

    <IfModule mod_litespeed.c>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Deny from env=DenyAccess
        Deny from 5.45.69.4
        Deny from 192.99.15.141
        Deny from 149.56.241.211
        Deny from 31.222.187.197
    </IfModule>
# END iThemes Security - این خط را تغییر یا حذف نکنید

# This file was updated by Duplicator on 2018-12-05 08:05:28. See .htaccess.orig for the original .htaccess file.
# Please note that other plugins and resources write to this file. If the time-stamp above is different
# than the current time-stamp on the file system then another resource has updated this file.
# Duplicator only writes to this file once during the install process while running the installer.php file.

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(appadmin|user)($|/) - [L] #To Shailor's suggestion
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

laravel `htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you are able to see the Laravel login page but not submit it?

Comment: @Johannes yes! After successful login, it should redirect to `/appadmin/dashboard` but in any case it redirects to `/wp-login.php`

Comment: You said you followed the abovementioned guide, but why are you going two directory levels back here? `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';`

Comment: @Johannes based on folder structure of my project, there is an extra level between `laravel files` and `appadmin files` relative to guide

Answer (score 2):

recheck laravel and wordpress .htaccess files.
to exclude appadmin you should add this line to wp's .htaccess before any other RewriteRule. update your question with .htaccess files if this didn't solved your problem, i'll update my answer too

```
RewriteRule ^(appadmin|user)($|/) - [L]
```

Comment: The issue is related to `RewriteBase /`. The WordPress ` .htaccess` is located in the root folder of your domain and therefore redirects all requests to the wordpress installation. Try to leave out the `|user` in Shalior's reply and make sure the rule is located one line below the `Rewrite Base / `.